# From 2 to 3 dimensions: integrating a force along a contour/surface.

Tags: integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus, minimal-surfaces

I am studying the following problem:

[image]

Consider a closed contour $\mathcal{C}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $r(\theta)$ where $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ and $r(0)=r(2\pi)$ (let the center to be zero for simplicity). We know a point $\mathbf{p}$, and from $\mathbf{p}$ we can draw the two lines that are tangential to $\mathcal{C}$ at points $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$.

Now, along the section of the contour that is 'behind' the tangent points, there is a force acting normally to the contour and uniform in magnitude throughout. If we integrate this force, it turns out that, independently of the contour, the resultant (i) acts on the mid-point of $\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}$ and (ii) is proportional to the length of $\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}$.

**I would like to generalize this result to 3 dimensions.**

I have started thinking about the problem as follows. We now have a surface $\mathcal{S}$ defined by $r(\alpha,\beta)$, $\alpha,\beta\in[0,2\pi)$. From $p$, we now have a contour of tangential points on $\mathcal{S}$, but this contour does not necessarily lie in a plane. My **hunch** is that perhaps, as the resultant in 2 dimensions depended on a line, which is the minimal distance between two points, in 3 dimensions it might depend on the [minimal surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface) corresponding the contour of tangential points on $\mathcal{S}$.

Any ideas or relevant references will be greatly appreciated.

---

PS: To help visualize the problem, you can think of $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{S}$ as physical objects, and $\mathbf{p}$ as a point light source. The force acts along the object where light does not reach it.

Comment: The presence of $\mathbf p$ is a red herring; you're really asking about the integral of the unit normal field on an *open* contour or surface. And I'm pretty sure Stokes' theorem implies that the integral only depends on the boundary of your integration region, *i.e.* the points $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ in 2D, and the boundary contour in 3D. So if you just want to compute the integral, you can replace the surface with one having the same boundary on which the integral is easier to compute, such as a cone joining an arbitrary point $\mathbf q$ to the boundary.

Comment: In that case, the integral becomes $\oint(\mathbf x-\mathbf q)\times\mathrm d\mathbf x$ where the integral is taken along the contour of tangential points. One can see that the integral is independent of $\mathbf q$ because $\oint\mathrm d\mathbf x=0$, so you might as well take it to be the origin, yielding $\oint\mathbf x\times\mathrm d\mathbf x$.